# For how long has "as" been synonymous with "because" in British English?

Tags: meaning, british-english

In British English, it seems that "because" can always be replaced with "as." Here is an example of "as" meaning "because" in British English:

> I popped down to the shops as we were out of loo roll.

In American English, this would translate to:

> I went to the store because we were out of toilet paper.

Here is an example of "as" meaning "while" in American English:

> I farted loudly as I descended the stairs.

In British English, the preceding sentence would be ambiguous because "as" could mean "while" (the fart coincides with the descent) or "because" (the fart is a result of the descent).

Has this always been true? If "as" has two main meanings ("while" and "because"), which of these was the original? And when was the second meaning added?

Comment: Can you give some examples??

Comment: @HotLicks, I have added examples.

Comment: Let's see:  "There were hailstones because big because tennis balls."  Yep, that works!  (*Because* is a conjunction.  *As* is sometimes a conjunction.)

Comment: "As" means 1. "because", e.g. *We got wet in the rain as we were without an umbrella*; 2. "function" *We would have got wet if Tom hadn't used his jacket as an umbrella*; 3. "job" e.g. *Tom worked as a lifeguard*, and 4. "when" e.g. *It started to rain as we walked down to the seashore*. I believe there is no distinction between BrEng and AmEng.

Comment: @HotLicks, yes, but I don't understand how that relates to the question.

Comment: @Mari-LouA, you'll find that the use of "as" to mean "because" in American English is very rare. I have heard "for" used to mean "because" just as often, which is to say approximately twice. But this does not address the question, which is whether "as" has always had "because" as one of its meanings and, if not, when it was added.

Comment: You ask if they're "totally interchangeable".  Clearly they're not.

Comment: @HotLicks, I'm afraid that's not the question at all. I did assert it at the start, which I'll correct for completeness. But the question is whether "as" has always had "because" as one of its meanings. If this isn't clear in the question, can you suggest a clarification?

Comment: Then why do you say *"as" is totally interchangeable with "because"*?

Comment: @HotLicks, that doesn't look like a question...

Comment: No, it looks like an "unclear what you're asking".

Comment: @HotLicks, thank you for trying to help, but in the interest of decorum I'll suggest we both move on.

Comment: If the first line of your question does not reflect your working assumptions I would suggest that you edit the question and change it.

Comment: I don't know who has voted to close the question - but (as least as currently edited) it is a perfectly reasonable question for British English (which is what it's tagged as).

Comment: The OED says that both senses date from Old English, although it adds that the meaning *because* was uncommon in the 16th and first half of the 17th century. From 1385 (spelling modernized): *as thou art full of joy and I am full of care, thou help me out of sin*. 1440 (spelling modernized) *as he slept, another came to home-ward.* As to which was the original, there are three or four other meanings of *as* which might qualify as well.

Comment: I don't particularly appreciate any of your examples, which appear to be little more than school boy humor / humour. You say that the 2nd sentence is ambiguous in BrEng  but I disagree, common sense and life experience tells us that walking down a flight of stairs do not cause someone to 'fart'. "As it was raining we stopped a stopped/ hailed a taxi" is a better example  IMO.